# Reading integers from a file and store it in a 2D vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, vector, iomanip

I've a problem in reading from a file and saving back in a 2D vector. This is the function that write on the file:

```
void create_input (int num_frames, int height, int width)
{
    ofstream GridFlow;

    GridFlow.open ("GridDB");

    for (int i = 0; i < num_frames; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < width; k++)
            {
                GridFlow << setw(5);
                GridFlow << rand() % 256 << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    GridFlow.close();
}
```

That simply writes a random number for each line (height * width * num_frames) number of times. Like this:

```
    3
   74
  160
   78
   15
   30
  127
   64
  178
   15
  107
```

What I want to do is to read back from the file and save different chunks of the file (width * height) in different frames. I've tried to do this but the program blocks without any error:

```
vector<Frame> movie;
movie.resize(num_frames);

for (int i = 0; i < num_frames; i++)
{
    Frame frame;

    int offset = i*width*height*6;

    vector<vector<int>>tmp_grid(height, vector<int>(width, 0));

    ifstream GridFlow;
    GridFlow.open ("GridDB");
    GridFlow.seekg(offset, GridFlow.beg);

    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int g = 0; g < width; g++)
        {
            int value;

            GridFlow >> value;

            tmp_grid[h][g] = value;
        }
    }

    frame.grid = tmp_grid;
    movie[i] = frame;
}
```

I've used an offset that each time is multiplied by 6 (number of bytes * line) to start reading, the structure Frame is only a 2D vector to store the values. I've to do this with the offset because the next step will be doing this multi threading, each thread knowing the number of the frame should compute the right offset to start reading and storing.

Comment: no errors thrown, nothing  ?

Comment: Off topic: Recommend writing binary, not text to the file. Much smaller file (6x), easier to predict boundaries (but you've done a great job here restricting the bounds), and you won't have to convert from text to integer. Should get you a large speed boost because you can suck the whole file up into one big array of bytes in one shot and then partition the array among threads..

Comment: Anyway, a block or busy-spin should be an easy problem to spot with the debugger that came with your development environment.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem, it successfully writes and loads data for me. Please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example so it'll be easier to help you ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Comment: @user4581301: but if I don't use binary but text, my method to read is semantically/syntactically correct? or I need to convert and/or to skip from one line to another in another way?

Comment: There are no lines. One frame-full will be exactly `GridFlow.read((char*)frame.grid, width * height * pixel depth)` and the offset would be `frameNo * width * height * pixel depth`. However, I'd read all of the frames sequentially and then fire up the threads to process the frames. I don't think you will gain much from threading the frame reads because without the text-to-number conversion the reads will probably wind up mostly sequential anyway with the threads queuing for file system access. You'd have to profile that to see if I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the file is like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
```

Here's one approach on how you could read the file into a vector and output it to another file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    using vvint = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
    std::ifstream file{ "file.txt" };
    vvint vec;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::string str_num;
        std::vector<int> temp;
        while (std::getline(ss, str_num, ',')) {
            temp.emplace_back(std::stoi(str_num));
        }
            vec.emplace_back(temp);
    }

    std::ofstream out_file{ "output.txt" };
    for (const auto& i : vec) {
        for (const auto& j : i) {
            out_file << j << ", ";
        }
        out_file << '\n';
    }
}
```